# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”?

Tags: c, xcode, command-line, exc-bad-access

I am making a command line program in C using XCode. When running the program, it initially does what it is supposed to do (asks me for a file path). However, when I type in a valid and existing file path, it gives me the following error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all (gdb)
```

I have two warnings in my program, both of which have to do with the function strcat. The warnings are:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcat'
```

and

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcat'
```

I am wondering why my program is not executing properly.

Thanks,
Mike

My code is posted below:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
int main (void)
{
   char *string1;
   printf("Type in your file path: ");
   scanf("%s", string1);
   char *string2 = "tar czvf YourNewFile.tar.gz ";
   strcat(string2, string1);
   system(string2);
}
```

Maybe it has to do with allocating the chars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examine this line:

```
char *string1
```

and this line:

```
scanf("%s", string1);
```

You have not declared a size for string1, meaning that you will always get an error, fix it with something like this:

`char string1[100]`

If 100 is the maximum length of your input.

Or read your input character by character.

And, to get rid of the warnings, add `#include "string.h"` to where your `#include` statements are.

Comment: Allocate memory for the other string, too. That's what mu is too short is trying to point out.

Comment: I'm really really new to this, how would I allocate memory for it? I know its alloc, butl ike is it something as simple as:
    char * = [string1 alloc]?

Comment: That's not how you do it. Do it the way I showed for string1, so like this:

Comment: Thank you very much! It runs through now, but I don't think it actually makes the tar.gz. But you solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: As soon as I get enough reputation I will. And its works perfectly! I just had to run the commandline instead of just clicking "Build and Run".

Comment: I'll give you the upvote in Mike's place, the memory allocation issue was the big one.

Comment: Something I noticed on XCode 7.1 at least with OSX is that I was getting program crashes that would occur about 15 lines down in the code past this mistake I made by not using the `[x]` sizing on the sprintf, scanf, and functions like that. For instance, I was doing a POSIX msgrcv that would crash with a pthread error. So, it can be hard to chase. I was chasing the wrong things until I read this post, fixed that problem in my string variable for the sprintf, and now my crashes don't occur.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to allocate space for `string1`, `scanf` will not allocate memory for you, you have to do that yourself. Furthermore, `string2` points at non-writeable memory and it doesn't have enough room to append `string1` to it anyway so your `strcat` would overflow even if you had `char string2[] = "tar czvf YourNewFile.tar.gz ";`.

Here's an annotated version of something that's closer to what you really want:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, sprintf, fgets */
#include <string.h> /* strcat, strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc */

#define TAR "tar czvf YourNewFile.tar.gz"

int main(void) {
    char path[100] = { 0 };  /* Initialize to all 0 bytes.           */
    char *cmd;               /* We'll allocate space for this later. */
    int   len;

    printf("Type in your file path: ");
    fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdin);   /* Read at most 100 characters into path */

    /*
     * Remove the trailing newline (if present).
     */
    len = strlen(path);
    if(path[len - 1] == '\n')
        path[len - 1] = '\0';

    /*
     * Allocate room for our command. 
     */
    cmd = malloc(
          strlen(TAR)   /* Room for the base tar command.         */
        + 1             /* One more for the space.                */
        + strlen(path)  /* Room for the path we read.             */
        + 1             /* One more for the final nul terminator. */
    );

    /*
     * You could also use a bunch of strcpy and strcat stuff for
     * this but sprintf is less noisy and safe as long as you've
     * properly allocated your memory.
     */
    sprintf(cmd, "%s %s", TAR, path);

    /*
     * This is vulnerable to unpleasant things in `path` (such as spaces,
     * &, >, <, ...) but this will do as a learning exercise. In real life
     * you'd probably want to use fork and exec for this to avoid the  
     * interface issues with the shell.
     */
    system(cmd);  

    /*
     * Free the memory we allocated.
     */
    free(cmd);

    /*
     * You need a return value because of "int main(...)". Zero is
     * the standard "all's well" return value.
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Someone please let me know if I've made any off-by-one errors.

You can find reference material for the functions in the above [over here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/index.html).

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm really new to programming (I started a couple days ago), so I really appreciate the help. So I will have to allocate memory for both strings?

Comment: @Mike: I added an annotated and corrected version of your code.

Comment: :) I didn't know professors were broke. I'm in middle school, so, no issues with money here :)

Comment: @Dhaivat: AFAIK, profs do okay but undergrad and grad students not so much.